# Where do the <unknown> items come from?

Tags: applications, quick-settings

At the quick settings dropdown are some items that have no icon and just a label . They cannot be re-arranged and are obviously useless.
Please have a look at the Screenshot

[image: screenshot].

I would like to know how I can find the apps or files that are responsible for those and/or a way how to get rid of them.

It is an Android Oreo with some EMUI on top.

Comment: Those are may be tiles reserved by the Automate app.

Comment: Good tip, I have Automate installed and this could be an option. I need to check that.

Comment: Dear moderators, I made a mistake and up and downvoted the comment of @ballzak. I should be upvoted. Can you correct that, please? I am sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @ballzak You were absolutely right, they came from the Automate app. Unfortunately I made a mistake at your comment and clicked the downvote without reading the warning. Could you pleas create a new one so that I can upvote? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use [Automate app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&hl=en_GB)? Those are for making a custom quick settings functions. You can customize them from the app by adding a "quick settings" block and defining its action.

Answer (score 0):

**How can I find apps responsible for creating these tiles?**

- Check in the manifest of each app for [Tile Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService). It will have `android:name=".MyQSTileService"` & `android:permission="android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE">` & service as `action android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE"`.

Since you don't know which app created this checking the manifest is going to be painfully slow. I used this app [apk analyser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sk.styk.martin.apkanalyzer&hl=en) to check for service and found for example `eu.faircode.email.ServiceTileUnseen` (it's an email app and the tile corresponds to unseen mails).

**How to hide them?**

I am not conversant with EMUI but here are things you can try to get them out of sight:

- [Customize tiles](https://www.huaweicentral.com/emui-10-tip-how-to-customize-shortcut-switches/) by

  - swiping down from the Status bar to open the notification panel.
  - Touch the pencil icon on the top right corner.
  - Drag Icons from the top part to the bottom part
- Or use an app like [Quick Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.simonesestito.ntiles&hl=en_US&gl=US&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Demui+quick+setting+tiles&pcampaignid=APPU_1_YSPMX8L5Hp-a4-EP2e-4qAM) to delete those  bothersome tiles

Comment: You can improve the answer by suggesting edit to reflect the steps on your device

Comment: Customize tiles doesn't really help. The icons are already out of the default sight, but I don't really like the idea to have such things on my device without any clue about their origin. I need to check "Quick Settings".
Most promising seems to be the "Apk Analyzer" and the tip of @ballzak in regard to Automate. Is it possible to lookup the manifest via Termux and its tools?

Comment: I don't think it is possible via Termux - that could be a separate question